# Please help me identify this SMD component

Tags: circuit-analysis, voltage

I've got a motor driver controller, I found an SMD component that is the same component shown in the picture.

I need help identifying this component. I've tried to google the part number, but no luck.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe it's an BC945? Not sure though as I can't quite see how many pins the component has.

Comment: Capsule is SOT-89. Can you trace where the pins go and sketch a small circuit around the mystery component to help us narrow it down?

Comment: Thanks you it has 4 pins